# Remote storage on ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, storage, remote, cloud

I have an Ubuntu server having limited storage, 30GB.
I need extra 100GB, how can I have a remote storage or remote drive which does *not* occupy local space?
Cloud services like dropbox take local space, too.

Comment: What is your budget ? What requirements do you have for latency/speed availability etc ?

Answer (score 0):

if you had a VPS you could use something like SSHFS to provide more disk space from the remote machine, however the performance will not be the best, so i wouldn't recommend it for anything high impact.

EDIT: you could of course use NFS. but you'd want that on your local network.